# form.validate is not a function error when using jquery-validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-steps

I am trying to use jquery validate and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.validate is not a function
```

Here is the order that my scripts are being referenced when I load the site since the first thing to be assumed is that I might be loading jquery after jquery-validation (but I am not):

```
<head>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- BOTTOM OF PAGE -->
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The form is declared in the html like this:

```
<form id="example-form" action="/MyController/Wizard" method="post">
</form>
```

Additionally here is my JavaScript code:

```
var form = $("#example-form");
form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the JavaScript files loading correctly?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @magreenberg jQuery 2.2.0

Comment: @BlakeRivell If I am looking at the right documentation. It's an older plugin. Try useing jquery `v1.11.1`.

Comment: @magreenberg Which is an older plugin: jQuery Steps or jQuery Validate? I am assuming jQuery Steps since jQuery Validate comes with ASP.NET which comes with jQuery 2.2.0...

Comment: @BlakeRivell It will be really hard for us to help since more information is needed. Do you have a live sever you can show so we can replicate the error?

Comment: @magreenberg a new ASP.NET MVC6 project comes with the following 3 bower packages and versions...     "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.5" I am not sure how the built in asp.net validation works if jquery validation doesn't work with jQuery 2.2.0... Unless we are talking about two different validation plugins here..

Comment: No I do not have anything live, but if you are an asp.net person: in order to reproduce you would basically create a new ASP.NET 5 MVC application using Visual Studio 2015 and keep all of the defaults. Install jQuery Steps bower package and then try to do the Basic Form example on this site: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples.. I don't expect you to do all of this though I thought my issue would be something stupid/simple. Another thing I am trying to do is create a clean simple html5 site using initializr adding jQuery steps and validation to it and try to get one of those examples going.

Comment: trying move the validate plugin to the end of the `head`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102913/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-magreenberg).